# Can an iPhone be "reset" without updating to a new iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

I'm reading too many conflicting things about this, so I'm asking here in the hopes to get a reasonably current, informed answer/solution.

I have an original iPhone SE an I love it.  It's the perfect phone for my needs, in every way.  I don't want anything bigger, I don't need anything faster.  I also absolutely do not want to update to any iOS newer than what I currently run, which is 14.8.1.  (Please don't try to convince me otherwise or lecture me on why one should always keep their phone updated etc.  I am comfortable with what I'm doing and it's my choice to make.)

Over time, my phone performance has degraded.  I know this isn't the hardware's fault per se, I've been on the same OS for ages and have just watched it gradually get slower, and less stable.  I would like to wipe and restore it, in order to "clear out" any cruft that has built up over all these years.  But, I need to be certain that the OS won't be upgraded and I'm not sure if that's possible, and if it is possible then how to do so.

**Is there any possible way I can wipe and restore my phone, without upgrading to a newer OS?  And if so, how?**

Answer (score 1):

There IS in fact a way to do this VERY EASILY.  The answer is to just reset from within the phone itself (Settings > General > Erase All Content and Settings) as demonstrated in [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=w22Nn6LqUSc).

I did this and everything restored from my iCloud backup perfectly, and I'm still on my same iOS.  The phone feels much more responsive now.